# Partner Community license assignment

Tags: community, partner-communities

I have following scenario and want to set up partner community license.

1. Have profile Customer service rep.
2. He has access to only Order object.

i know we need to set Account as partner and then contacts need to be enabled as partner and then create user and assign the partner community profile.
But if i have no.of users and want to assign them Partner Community License  and Customer service repprofile, how i should proceed to implement this?

Could you please suggest?

Comment: Are you asking if you can create these users in batch rather than individually?

Comment: No actually want to know assignment of partner community profile to users.. best approach

Comment: Is the Customer Service Rep profile a Salesforce or Community user profile?